# Complete graph has two edge disjoint spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I read that a complete graph $K_n$ for $n \geq 4$ has (at least) two edge disjoint spanning trees. I know that the graph has to contain at least one spanning tree and I can show this for $n=4$. I hope that this result can be shown by induction, but honestly I don't really know how to do the induction. As I mentioned, the case $n=4$ can be shown be shown by an image, which I have done on paper. If it holds for an $n \geq 4$, however, I don't know how to show it for $n+1$. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As you noted,  the result for $n=4$ is easy;  simply exhibit the required spanning trees.
Now for $n>4$,  take any spanning tree, $T$. Every tree has at least two leaves, so pick a leaf $L$. It is adjacent to exactly one edge, $e$,  in $T$.

$K_{n}$$\setminus$$L$ is $K_{n-1}$  and $T$$\setminus$$e$ is a spanning tree for $K_{n}$$\setminus$$L$.  By the induction hypothesis, $K_{n}$$\setminus$$L$ has at least one spanning tree, S, that is edge-disjoint from $T$$\setminus$$e$ in $K_{n}$$\setminus$$L$.  Add any edge in $K_{n}$ other than $e$ that is adjacent to $L$ and join it to $S$.  That is now an edge disjoint spanning tree for $K_{n}$.